# Many-to-many relationship. How do I connect tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, many-to-many

I have a question about many-to-many relationships.  I currently have three tables:

- movie
- genre
- movie_genre

Within the 'movie' table I have columns:

- id_movie
- title (example: X-Men)
- rel_year (release date)
- img_src (displays image saved on server. This is also what shows up on website using php to link to page)
- page_link (links to page...)

Within the 'genre' table I have columns:

- id_genre
- name (Action, Adventure, etc... There are 14 genres)

Within the 'movie_genre' table I have columns:

- id_movie_genre
- id_movie
- id_genre

I want to be able to connect these databases so that I can sort the data on my website by genre depending on the page.  For instance, if I wanted to see every movie under 'Action' I would only want to display those saved in my database with that id.

How do I go about connecting my data to match my example?  Any help or advice is welcome, I am still VERY new to mySQL and php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a join (an SQL concept).  You should become very familiar with joins very quickly.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    movie
    NATURAL JOIN movie_genres
    NATURAL JOIN genre
WHERE
    genre.name = 'Action'
```

Edit: Inserting a relationship between one movie and three genres:

```
INSERT INTO movie_genre
    (movie_id, genre_id)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
```

Comment: So if I wanted to add a movie with an 'id_movie' of '1' and give it 'id_genre' of '1,2, and 3'. I would just add '1' three times in the 'id_movie' column and then assign '1,2, and 3' to each one?  When I print this with php it will know which title I am referring to?  Sorry if this question made no sense....

Answer (score 1):

In a pinch, this will join your tables.  Then you can restrict the results down with `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT g.name, m.*
FROM movie m
JOIN movie_genre mg ON mg.id_movie = m.id_movie
JOIN genre g ON g.id_genre = mg.id_genre;
```

Note that the linking table (`movie_genre`) should not have its own unique ID.  Its primary key should be the two table IDs that it joins, and that's all.